# C# to C++ 'Gotchas'

Tags: c#, c++

I have been developing a project that I absolutely must develop part-way in C++.  I need develop a wrapper and expose some C++ functionality into my C# app.  I have been a C# engineer since the near-beginning of .NET, and have had very little experience in C++.  It still looks very foreign to me when attempting to understand the syntax.

Is there anything that is going to knock me off my feet that would prevent me from just picking up C++ and going for it?

Comment: Are you using plain C++ or C++/CLI?

Comment: C++ and C# are completely different languages - they have very little in common.

Comment: It might not knock you off a feet, but I found it most irritating when I forget to end a class definition with `;` in C++... I mean, why, just why? Doesn't the `}` say everything?

Comment: @Noldorin No: struct A {} a;

Comment: @Noldorin - personally now that I have to switch between the two regularly, I wish C# had kept the `;` even though it is superfluous there. And `public: private: protected:` as pseudo-labels instead of modifiers on individual members. And private inheritance as the default (I don't think the CLR's type system allows for that though).

Comment: Use Qt, with it you can have threads communicating with message passing (signal/slots). QString are like C# strings.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

C++ has so many gotchas that I can't enumerate them all. Do a search for "C# vs C++". A few basic things to know:
In C++:

- struct and a class are basically the same thing (Default visibility for a struct is public, it's private for a class).
- Both struct and class can be created either on the heap or the stack.
- You have to manage the heap yourself. If you create something with "new", you have to delete it manually at some point.
- If performance isn't an issue and you have very little data to move around, you can avoid the memory management issue by having everything on the stack and using references (& operator).
- Learn to deal with .h and .cpp. Unresolved external can be you worse nightmare.
- You shouldn't call a virtual method from a constructor. The compiler will never tell you so I do.
- Switch case doesn't enforce "break" and go thru by default.
- There is not such a thing as an interface. Instead, you have class with pure virtual methods.
- C++ aficionados are dangerous people living in cave and surviving on the fresh blood of C#/java programmers. Talk with them about their favorite language carefully.

Comment: Hehe. My first answer post. Didn't even know about SO markup!

Comment: I disagree with #4. Often, you get best performance by avoiding heap allocations. You save the (significant) overhead of excessive new/delete calls, and you get better cache locality.

Comment: To Jalf: good point. It really depends on the size of the data and what you do with it. I believe pointers are overrated and we can do a lot without them.

Comment: About #6: calling virtual functions in a constructor or desctructor in C++ is perfectly legal and has well-defined effects, so no wonder the compiler does not bark. However, Scott Meyers warns that "you shouldn't call virtual functions during construction or destruction, because the calls won't do what you think, and if they did, you'd still be unhappy" (see e.g. <http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html>).

Comment: To fred: there is also the issue of pure virtual method being called by a constructor. The compiler doesn't bark but it will crash at runtime.

Comment: About #6: Calling a virtual method virtually might not do what you want. Calling it statically might though.

Comment: If you call a virtual method from a constructor, that means you are really a bad programmer and you should distance yourself from OOP BS and get back to the reality.

Answer (score 26):

**Garbage collection!**

Remember that everytime you `new` an object, you *must* be responsible for calling `delete`.

Comment: Or you must use smart pointers, or some other type that manages the memory for you. Of course, it's possible that you shouldn't be using 'new' in the first place -  overuse of dynamic allocation is another problem C# and Java programmers have when coming to C++.

Comment: Very good point. You need to really get to grips with the difference between the stack and the heap: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

Comment: @Neil: I'd say that's the #1 gotcha the OP should be aware of. Should be an answer, really :) Every C# programmer who's spent even 3 minutes looking at C++ is aware that you have to call `delete`. That they should often avoid `new` entirely is much more surprising.

Answer (score 18):

There are a lot of differences, but the biggest one I can think of that programmers coming from Java/C# always get wrong, and which they never *realize* they've got wrong, is C++'s value semantics.

In C#, you're used to using `new` any time you wish to create an object. And whenever we talk about a class instance, we really mean "a reference to the class instance". `Foo x = y` doesn't copy the object `y`, it simply creates another reference to whatever object `y` references.

In C++, there's a clear distinction between local objects, allocated without `new` (`Foo f` or `Foo f(x, y)`, and dynamically allocated ones (`Foo* f = new Foo()` or `Foo* f = new Foo(x, y)`). And in C# terms, everything is a value type. `Foo x = y` actually creates a *copy* of the `Foo` object itself.

If you want reference semantics, you can use pointers or references: `Foo& x = y` creates a reference to the object `y`. `Foo* x = &y` creates a pointer to the address at which `y` is located. And copying a pointer does just that: it creates another pointer, which points to whatever the original pointer pointed to. So this is similar to C#'s reference semantics.

Local objects have *automatic storage duration* -- that is, a local object is automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. If it is a class member, then it is destroyed when the owning object is destroyed. If it is a local variable inside a function, it is destroyed when execution leaves the scope in which it was declared.

Dynamically allocated objects are not destroyed until *you* call `delete`.

So far, you're probably with me. Newcomers to C++ are taught this pretty soon.
The tricky part is in what this *means*, how it affects your programming style:

In C++, the *default* should be to create local objects. Don't allocate with `new` unless you absolutely have to.

If you do need dynamically allocated data, make it the responsibility of a class. A (very) simplified example:

```
class IntArrayWrapper {
  explicit IntArrayWrapper(int size) : arr(new int[size]) {} // allocate memory in the constructor, and set arr to point to it
  ~IntArrayWrapper() {delete[] arr; } // deallocate memory in the destructor

  int* arr; // hold the pointer to the dynamically allocated array
};
```

this class can now be created as a local variable, and it will *internally* do the necessary dynamic allocations. And when it goes out of scope, it'll automatically delete the allocated array again.

So say we needed an array of x integers, instead of doing this:

```
void foo(int x){
  int* arr = new int[x];
  ... use the array ...
  delete[] arr; // if the middle of the function throws an exception, delete will never be called, so technically, we should add a try/catch as well, and also call delete there. Messy and error-prone.
}
```

you can do this:

```
void foo(int x){
  IntArrayWrapper arr(x);
  ... use the array ...
  // no delete necessary
}
```

Of course, this use of local variables instead of pointers or references means that objects are copied around quite a bit:

```
Bar Foo(){
  Bar bar;
  ... do something with bar ...
  return bar;
}
```

in the above, what we return is a *copy* of the `bar` object. We could return a pointer or a reference, but as the instance created inside the function goes out of scope and is destroyed the moment the function returns, we couldn't point to that. We *could* use `new` to allocate an instance that outlives the function, and return a function to *that* -- and then we get all the memory management headaches of figuring out whose responsibility it is to delete the object, and when that should happen. That's not a good idea.

Instead, the `Bar` class should simply be designed so that copying it does what we need. Perhaps it should internally call `new` to allocate an object that can live as long as we need it to. We could then make copying or assignment "steal" that pointer. Or we could implement some kind of reference-counting scheme where copying the object simply increments a reference counter and copies the pointer -- which should then be deleted not when the individual object is destroyed, but when the *last* object is destroyed and the reference counter reaches 0.

But often, we can just perform a deep copy, and clone the object in its entirety. If the object includes dynamically allocated memory, we allocate more memory for the copy.
It may sound expensive, but the C++ compiler is good at eliminating unnecessary copies (and is in fact in most cases allowed to eliminate copy operations even if they have side effects).

If you want to avoid copying even more, and you're prepared to put up with a little more clunky usage, you can enable "move semantics" in your classes as well as (or instead of) "copy semantics". It's worth getting into this habit because (a) some objects can't easily be copied, but they can be moved (e.g. a `Socket` class), (b) it's a pattern established in the standard library and (c) it's getting language support in the next version.

With move semantics, you can use objects as a kind of "transferable" container. It's the contents that move. In the current approach, it's done by calling `swap`, which swaps the contents of two objects of the same type. When an object goes out of scope, it is destructed, but if you swap its contents into a reference parameter first, the contents escape being destroyed when the scope ends. Therefore, you don't necessarily need to go all the way and use reference counted smart pointers just to allow complex objects to be returned from functions. The clunkiness comes from the fact that you can't really *return* them - you have to swap them into a reference parameter (somewhat similar to a `ref` parameter in C#). But the language support in the next version of C++ will address that.

So the biggest C# to C++ gotcha I can think of: don't make pointers the default. Use value semantics, and instead tailor your classes to behave the way you want when they're copied, created and destroyed.

A few months ago, I attempted to write a series of blog posts for people in your situation:
[Part 1](http://jalf.dk/blog/2009/08/a-net-developers-guide-to-c/)
[Part 2](http://jalf.dk/blog/2009/09/a-net-developers-guide-to-c-part-ii/)
[Part 3](http://jalf.dk/blog/2009/10/a-net-developers-guide-to-c-part-iii/)

I'm not 100% happy with how they turned out, but you may still find them useful.

And when you feel that you're never going to get a grip on pointers, [this](http://jalf.dk/blog/2009/07/the-great-pointer-conspiracy/) post may help.

Comment: I'm itching to edit this to include a mention of `swap` - it's a clunky-but-effective approach to codifying move semantics, and is a damn sight simpler than going all the way to reference counting. Build a big object as a local inside a function, then "return" it by swapping it into a non-const ref parameter.

Comment: Feel free to edit it. :) I decided not to describe too many specifics (I didn't mention smart pointers either, although I pretty much described their precise semantics), but if you feel it's relevant, edit all you like. You're right, `swap` is a pretty important part of making C++'s value semantics play nice.

Comment: Added something, delete it if you think it's a crazy digression.

Comment: In C#: "Foo x = y" does not copy the object, it just sets the reference of x = y if Foo is a class object reference.

Answer (score 6):

**No run-time checks**

One C++ pitfall is the behaviour when you try to do something that might be invalid, but which can only be checked at runtime - for example, dereferencing a pointer that could be null, or accessing an array with an index that might be out of range.

The C# philosophy emphasises correctness; all behaviour should be well-defined and, in cases like this, it performs a run-time check of the preconditions and throws well-defined exceptions if they fail.

The C++ philosophy emphasises efficiency, and the idea that you shouldn't pay for anything you might not need. In cases like this, nothing will be checked for you, so you must either check the preconditions yourself or design your logic so that they must be true. Otherwise, the code will have undefined behaviour, which means it might (more or less) do what you want, it might crash, or it might corrupt completely unrelated data and cause errors that are horrendously difficult to track down.

Comment: Yes, I think this is THE basic fundamental difference. To understand the runtime semantics of a language, you need to look at the spec. The C++ spec is founded on the approach of distinguishing between operations with defined results and operations with an undefined result. The "safe" subset of the CLR (which is all most languages/people ever bother with) is founded on the notion of completely defined behaviour.

Comment: NB. Most decent C++ implementations do define the behaviour of some operations that are undefined in the standard. e.g. resizing a vector invalidates any associated iterators - attempting to use such an iterator results in undefined behaviour. But on many implementations, in "debug" builds, it reliably results in a helpful message.

Comment: +5 for saying "The C++ philosophy emphasises efficiency, and the idea that you shouldn't pay for anything you might not need."

Answer (score 4):

Just to throw in some others that haven't been mentioned yet by other answers:

**const**: C# has a limited idea of const.  In C++ 'const-correctness' is important.  Methods that don't modify their reference parameters should take const-references, eg.

```
void func(const MyClass& x)
{
    // x cannot be modified, and you can't call non-const methods on x
}
```

Member functions that don't modify the object should be marked const, ie.

```
int MyClass::GetSomething() const // <-- here
{
    // Doesn't modify the instance of the class
    return some_member;
}
```

This might seem unnecessary, but is actually very useful (see the next point on temporaries), and sometimes required, since libraries like the STL are fully const-correct, and you can't cast const things to non-const things (*don't* use const_cast! Ever!).  It's also useful for callers to know something won't be changed.  It is best to think about it in this way: if you omit const, you are saying the object *will* be modified.

**Temporary objects**: As another answer mentioned, C++ is much more about value-semantics.  Temporary objects can be created and destroyed in expressions, for example:

```
std::string str = std::string("hello") + " world" + "!";
```

Here, the first + creates a temporary string with "hello world".  The second + combines the temporary with "!", giving a temporary containing "hello world!", which is then copied to *str*.  After the statement is complete, the temporaries are immediately destroyed.  To further complicate things, C++0x adds rvalue references to solve this, but that's way out of the scope of this answer!

You can also bind temporary objects to const references (another useful part of const).  Consider the previous function again:

```
void func(const MyClass& x)
```

This can be called explicitly with a temporary MyClass:

```
func(MyClass()); // create temporary MyClass - NOT the same as 'new MyClass()'!
```

A MyClass instance is created, *on the stack*, func2 accesses it, and then the temporary MyClass is destroyed *automatically* after func returns.  This is convenient and also usually very fast, since the heap is not involved.  Note 'new' returns a pointer - not a reference - and requires a corresponding 'delete'.  You can also directly assign temporaries to const references:

```
const int& blah = 5;   // 5 is a temporary
const MyClass& myClass = MyClass(); // creating temporary MyClass instance
// The temporary MyClass is destroyed when the const reference goes out of scope
```

Const references and temporaries are frequent in good C++ style, and the way these work is very different to C#.

**RAII**, exception safety, and deterministic destructors.  This is actually a useful feature of C++, possibly even an advantage over C#, and it's worth reading up on since it's also good C++ style.  I won't cover it here.

Finally, I'll just throw in **this** is a pointer, not a reference :)

Answer (score 2):

The traditional stumbling blocks for people coming to C++ from C# or Java are memory management and polymorphic behavior:

- While objects always live on the heap and are garbage collected in C#/Java, you can have objects in static storage, stack or the heap ('free store' in standard speak) in C++. You have to cleanup the stuff you allocate from the heap (new/delete). An invaluable technique for dealing with that is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

  Inheritance/polymorphism work only *through pointer or reference* in C++.

There are many others, but these will probably get you first.

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual destructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Virtual_destructors).

Answer (score 2):

**Header files!** You'll find yourself asking, "so why do I need to write method declarations twice every time?"

Comment: You don't - you write one declaration and one definition.

Comment: aah, if only it was that simple :D

Comment: ...you know what I mean. And yes I know template classes only get written once as well, before that one gets commented.

Comment: Unless you enjoy typing the same thing twice, you write one declaration and then copy and paste it and delete the semi-colon to start the definition. Then when you need to add another parameter, you have to do it in two places. This is the crux of the matter I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Pointers and Memory Allocation**

...I'm a C# guy too and I'm still trying to wrap my head around proper memory practices in C/C++.

Comment: The funny part there is that pointers should be really natural for C# and Java people. References in those languages are actually pointers in disguise, now having to deallocate makes a difference. (And knowing that you do not actually need to create all objects with new

Comment: It's not that pointers are odd for C# and Java people, it's that non-pointers are odd, and in C++ are semantically simpler than pointers.

Comment: @David Rodriguez - I suspect the problem of understanding starts when they first encounter the ++ operator being applied to a pointer. Indeed, it could be said that this is the root problem with C and C++ - next to every object, there is another object. Possibly.

Comment: When I say "problem" of course I mean "for dumb people". There, that should avoid a language war! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief overview of Managed C++ [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliintro01.aspx). An article about writing an Unmanaged wrapper using the Managed C++ [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/ManagedWrapperSample.aspx). There is another article here about mixing Unmanaged with Managed C++ code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/mixnetnative.aspx).

Using Managed C++ would IMHO make it easier to use as a bridge to the C# world and vice versa.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is C#'s reference semantics (for most types) vs. C++'s value semantics.  This means that objects are copied far more often than they are in C#, so it's important to ensure that objects are copied correctly.  This means implementing a *copy constructor* and `operator=` for any class that has a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Raw memory twiddling.** Unions, memsets, and other direct memory writes. Anytime someone writes to memory as a sequence of bytes (as opposed to as objects), you lose much of the ability to reason about the code.

Comment: I've written a lot of C++ over the years - I can count the times I've used unions on the fingers of one hand. memset might require two hands. These are really C features that are very rarely used in C++.

Comment: Agreed, we don't write them often now... but you might end up working in some legacy code.

Comment: We never used them often - the "years" I was talking about began in the mid-80s.

Comment: In general, you can't treat memory as a sequence of bytes in C++ either. The language standard is actually fairly specific about this. Only in some very limited cases is it safe to think of memory as a sequence of bytes. In general, no, it's no more allowed than it is in C#.

Comment: @jalf, while technically true, it doesn't really hold up as a comparison. The C++ standard guarantees that if you have a pointer to an object, you can conveniently access two objects on either side of it *as far as the compiler is concerned*, regardless of whether the object is embedded in an array of properly constructed objects of the same type. In the CLR such positional access is limited at the lowest level specifically to arrays. And an array of references to objects contains either nulls or references to constructed objects (although sadly not necessarily of the right types - whoops).

Comment: @Earwicker: The standard doesn't guarantee that the compiler will accept that. A sufficiently clever compiler *could* generate an error whenever you tried that trick. Of course in practice you're right, C# slaps you over the wrist if you try anything silly like this, where a C++ compiler just pretends that all is well, but neither language *allow* you to treat memory as a sequence of bytes. They just differ in how aggressively they require the "high level" view of memory to be enforced.

Answer (score 0):

**Linking**

Linking with external libraries is not as forgiving as it is in .Net, `$DEITY` help you if you mix something compiled with different flavors of the same msvcrt (debug, multithread, unicode...)

**Strings**

And you'll have to deal with Unicode vs Ansi strings, these are not exactly the same.

Have fun :)

Answer (score -4):

**The following isn't meant to dissuade in any way :D**

C++ is a minefield of Gotcha's, it's relatively tame if you don't use templates and the STL -- and just use object orientation, but even then is a monster. In that case object based programming (rather than object-oriented programming) makes it even tamer -- often this form of C++ is enforced in certain projects (i.e., don't use any features that have even a chance of being naively used).

However you should learn all those things, as its a very powerful language if you do manage to traverse the minefield.If you want to learn about gotcha's you better get the books from Herb Sutter, Scott Myers, and Bjarne Stroustrup. Also Systematically going over the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) will help you to realize that it indeed does require 10 or so books to turn into a good C++ programmer.

Comment: No, the way to "tame" C++ is to make use of the STL. Avoiding the redeeming features of C++ doesn't exactly make it easier to use.

Comment: you've typed a 4 page "stream of conciousness" and touched on some of the issues in C+++, that a new programmer has no hope of comprehending. Yet it is evil for me to even hint at suggesting a simplification to the approach of learning C++. The feature-set of C++ should be learned a construct at a time. C++ is simply not a straight-forward language.

Comment: I agree with that. But pretending that C++ gets *simpler* by avoiding the standard library is just silly. There are many other features that it makes sense to avoid in order to simplify the language. But avoiding the STL forces you to manually handle memory management, and use pointers and raw arrays everywhere, which is far more complex and error-prone than using a few STL classes.

Comment: The STL doesn't magically make the issues you are talking about go away, and if you don't understand how the STL is doing things your not going to consistently gain from it --i.e., it might seem to be designed to allow novice's to solve simple problems, but that wasn't its raison d'être. Real world programming problems solved by C++ will still require that you understand all sorts of nasty details that you seem to be suggesting the STL magically takes away. All I am trying to convey here is that its not ponies and teddy bears.

Comment: @Hassan:  What we're saying is not that you can't make suggestions, but that (in our experience) you're completely wrong.  A beginner should use `vector<>` and `shared_ptr<>` consistently, as a way of avoiding problems.  Using raw pointers and arrays is error-prone, and positively weird to somebody coming from a C# or Java background.  Yes, C++ has an unusual amount of gotchas.  No, the way to avoid them isn't to drop every language feature designed to simplify things.

Comment: Who said anything about dropping things ? You both seem to be reading more than is there.

Comment: I don't see why you are being downvoted. Someone shouldn't use templates and STL too much before mastering the basic of C++. Some part of STL can be used but a beginner, like containers but stuff like algo and iterator require to know C++ quite well. When I began programming C++, I used shared_ptr heavily. I came to learn that shared_ptr isn't such a great thing and can be avoided with better/different design.

Comment: @Hassan, I think you've highlighted C++'s main problem, which is that the world is awash with people advising its users to avoid taking advantage of any of the features that have been added to it since about 1988. *If* someone is determined to learn C++, there is no point in them avoiding the use of the standard library or limiting themselves only to "object oriented" programming.

Comment: @Simon T.:  Hassan was advocating staying away from the STL, at least at first, not just the more esoteric parts, which I consider a Bad Idea.  As far as `shared_ptr` goes, no, it isn't the solution to everything, but I strongly suggest that a beginner to C++ use it consistently.  Once beginners are no longer beginners, they can learn exactly what to use, why, and when.